# My heating coil was bent. Should it be replaced?

Tags: hvac, heating

I know nothing about home improvement so apologies if I have the terms wrong. My landlord sent someone inexperienced to replace my below-window AC unit, and the person somehow bent the heating coil above it. It's now sort of a wide upside down v shape, with one end almost an inch lower than the other.

Should I make the landlord replace the bent coil with a new one? (The landlord wants to try to unbend it.)

It's hard to capture it in photos, but here is my attempt. The first photo compares the bent coil unit to the normal one in the other room, so you can see how much it's bent.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your pictures leave the actual damages unclear, at least to me - they have been hyper-cropped and "censored" to the point that I can't see what the purported problem is.

Comment: @Ecnerwal and OPs comment under Ed Beal tells me he only wants certain answers to his question.  I agree the ultracropped pics side by side at the top appear to be showing something different than bent fins in the gigantic picture.

Comment: I cropped it to take out a reflection of myself in the window and other identifying markers. I'm trying to figure out whether this can be repaired and whether it would take longer than one would expect the staff to spend on it.

Answer (score 2):

If the heating coil belongs to the landlord and it is still functional (it heats the apartment when needed, without leaking, etc.), you really don't have any reason to "make" your landlord replace it, and making a great fuss about it would put you on the short list for not getting your lease renewed with any sensible landlord.

It's their property, if their chosen fix for the heater they own in the apartment they own is to bend it back into shape, you are merely a tenant who can choose not to renew your lease if that sort of repair is somehow offensive to your sensibilities. I don't think you'll have any luck from a legal standpoint trying to break your lease over it.

Answer (score 1):

The visible damage is minor and can be repaired (straightened) with the right size of fin combs. Count the number of fins per inch and that is the comb that is needed. A full set cost 15-25$ . Straightening takes a little time to do a really good job, starting with a undamaged section place the comb with the hooks to the damage and slowly slide the comb into the damaged area wiggling back and fourth lifting the folded over part. It may take several passes to fully straighten but I have repaired coils that the owner pressure washed folding over ~ 50% of the fins before realiseing he was damaging the coil. I think it took about an hour maybe longer but it saved a 5 ton unit that was only about 3 months old.

Comment: Ed Beal, thanks for the helpful response. I don't think they own a set of combs, just one. I also doubt anyone will spend more than 2 minutes on this. I've had a damaged/bent coil in the past, and it rattled constantly and I noticed that the unit didn't heat as well.

Comment: When the fins are folded that blocks the air flow and reduces the heat exchange.

Comment: Thanks. How much time would need to be spent without doing this right?

Comment: It depends on the tool used , I think those coils could be fixed in about 20 minutes with the right comb.